# Conclude $r$ is a simple zero

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

**Problem:**
Conclude that $r$ is a simple zero for $u,$ given that
$$u(x_n)=\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \: \: and \: \: u'(x_n)=\frac{1}{q}.$$

It's known that:

1. $f(x)$ is $q$ times continuous and differentiable with
   $$f(r)=f'(r)=...=f^{(q-1)}(r)=0 \: \: and \: \: f^{(q)}(0)\neq 0.$$
2. By Newton's Method:
   $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}.$$

**My Attempt:**
I want to show that $u(x_n)=0$, so I'm going to use Taylor expansion on $u(r)$ at $x_n:$
$$0=u(r)=u(x_n)+u'(x_n)(r-x_n)+\frac{1}{2}u''(\xi_n)(r-x_n)^2, \xi_n \in (r,x_n).$$

From here I'm thinking about dividing with $u'(x_n)$ since it's non-zero, but I'm having some trouble getting past the roadblock...

Any hints?

Comment: $u'(r)\ne 0$ means that $r$ is a simple root of $u$. Is this the original task or your interpretation of a part of it?

Comment: As written $r$ cannot be a root of $u(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f‘(x)}$ because that is not defined at $x=r$. But you can use l‘Hôpital to extend the given definition continuously into that point.